# Run local server on specific ip, node.js

Tags: node.js, server

I've created server

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    // ...
}).listen(3001);
```

And it runs on `localhost`, so in browser I can get it by `http://myipaddress:3001/`. Also i can get it from any machine in local network.

But if someone else will clone this project (someone who is not in local network) and run his local server, he would get it by `http://HISipaddress:3001/`, cause he have other ip address.

Is there way to run server on specific ip address, so the server would be available by the same way?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: *"Is there way to run server on specific ip address, so the server would be available by the same way"* No, because your ip address is the address of your computer in your network, or your network in the interwebs. You can sometimes specify what ip address you want inside a network, but not always, and i doubt that will solve the problem you're trying to solve anyway. Sounds like an X/Y problem to me. Instead of making your server run on a specific ip, make your app not care what ip/port it is ran on.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I've created server, and in my html/js I load resource by link `http://localhost:3001`. I also test it on mobile device, but on mobile device this link is unawailable cause `localhost` points on localhost of mobile device.

Comment: Why not use your IP address?

Comment: You probably need to `.listen(3001, '0.0.0.0');`. Then run `ifconfig` and see what your LAN IP is and use `http://LAN-IP:3001` in your phone browser. This will obviously only work if the phone and PC are on the same LAN.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, Yeah, it works fine, but then I need to load resource in my html from that server, and I need to use absolute path. And smth like `<video src="http://localhost:3001/video" width="300"></video>` works on desktop, but not working on device.

Comment: and if I use my IP address, it would not work if someone clone project, cause he have different ip.

Comment: `/video` is an absolute path where the `http://whatever:port` part is automatically added for you by the browser.